# Thymeleaf background img

Tags: html, css, spring, thymeleaf

Hello so i have a spring boot project and I am using thymeleaf as my view engine.In my project I have a registration form "registration.html" and I want to change the background img for the whole page.

this is the link in registration.html to the css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/css/common.css}"/>
```

and this is the css file named common.css

```
.background {
width: 100%;
background-image: url('../img/reg.jpg');
}
```

and this is the structure of the project the css file is located in resources/static/css and the image is in resources/static/img
[image]

The picture is not loading at all on the registration page
[image]

any ideas to why that is or how to fix it are appreciated.

Comment: Did you check whether the CSS file is loaded or not?

Comment: @TJ i am not sure how to check that, inspecting the page shows the css file as a used resource.I tried adding a background color to the css file and even that is not working the way I configured it. I have another page for the login and its css is working fine.

Comment: You can check the network tab to see if a request is being made for the image

Comment: @TJ i added body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #eee;

}   and that is correctly changing the color of the background but the image is still not loading so I think it something about the relative pathing

Comment: @TJ i chekced the network tab and it is infact loading the css file

Answer (score 1):

Change the .background class with body :

```
body
{
    background-image: url(Your image file path);
}
```

Comment: i tried doing that and it still doesn't work I'm starting to think it is the path that is the problem but I don't see how the path can be wrong.

Comment: The path is /src/main/resources/static/img/reg.jpg right?

Answer (score 0):

it may be something wrong with the path you're targeting.
but I hope this will work for you too:
.background should be a class in your HTML tag
you can try it bu giving background to your body first
and make sure it has width and height or a content in it to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was I have not allowed the mapping for the img in the spring security setup so it wasn't allowing unregistered users to see it, it had nothing to do with the pathing.